# How to map Qt push button to keyboard key presses

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I am having a widget with multiple push buttons with characters as name. I want my push button to be active(pressed) when I press a character in keyboard. ie, when I press 'a' in keyboard 'Push_button_A' should get pressed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

a) You can install and override event filter of a parent widget and handle the key press events in it.

b) Or you can add `QShortcut` object for each `QPushButton` object and connect their signals (`QShortcut::activated`) and slots to buttons (`QPushButton::click` or even better `QPushButton::animateClick`).

c) Or you can use mnemonic shortcut... see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#shortcut-prop and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#shortcut-prop Quoting: "If the text contains an ampersand character ('&'), a shortcut is automatically created for it. The character that follows the '&' will be used as the shortcut key. Any previous shortcut will be overwritten or cleared if no shortcut is defined by the text. See the QShortcut documentation for details. To display an actual ampersand, use '&&'."

Which solution to choose, it depends on how many button there are and if they are expected to be added dynamically or not and how the names/letters are about to be stored (is it hardcoded? or somehow dynamically settable? does it depend on language translations?). We have too little information about this based on your description, so we cannot tell you which way to go.

PS: there are probably even more possible solutions, but these three seem to me the simplest ones.

Comment: Shortcuts are usually used in combination with a Ctrl or Alt key. I think the OP just wanted the 'a' key by itself to trigger the button.

Comment: @JarMan Shortcuts can be used without modifiers... So I mentioned this option. Btw. mnemonic shortcuts do not have modifiers.

Comment: You might be right. But I'm just reading this [documenation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html#mnemonic) and it says it uses the Alt key.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Yes, you are right, it uses Alt key indeed. But nevertheless shortcuts do not necessarily need modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    switch (event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_A:
        on_Push_button_A_clicked();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Define keyPressEvent in your MainWindow. Call relevant push_button_clicked events after identifying the event key.